# I have not getting clear result about this issue

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Am New to selenium Webdriver i have one project called Smoke testing .ie testing all the websites links are working fine or not .if any link is broken or not working means that test report sending email to the specified url.Actually i have write some codes for testing all the links and all the websites are getting from excel sheet problem is if the link is not working bt it shows the result as it is working nu so i cannot know the exact solution.here am attaching that codes Especially all the websites are made up of Wordpress.

```
public class LinktestTest
    {
    public static WebDriver driver;


     @Test
     public void findurl() throws Throwable, IOException {
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("D:\\sample.xls");
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
    System.out.println("Program Started"+s.getName());
    System.out.println(s.getRows());
    for (int row = 0; row <= s.getRows()-1; row++) 
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    String Urllist = s.getCell(0, row).getContents().toString();
    System.out.println("Urllist" + Urllist);
    driver.get(Urllist);
    List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    String[] linkTexts = new String[linkElements.size()];
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    int j = 0;
    for (WebElement e : linkElements) {
    linkTexts[j] = e.getText();
    j++;
    }

    // test each link
    for (String t : linkTexts) {
    if (t != null && !t.isEmpty()) {
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(t)).click();
    String title;
    title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("title is"+title);
    if((title.contains("You are not authorized to view this page"))||(title.contains("404")) ||
     (title.contains("408"))|| (title.contains("400")) || (title.contains("401"))
      || (title.contains("403"))||(title.contains("Page not found"))||(title.contains("500"))||(title.contains("error"))||(title.contains("503 Service Unavailable")))
    {
    System.out.println(t + " the link is not working");
    } else {
    System.out.println("\"" + t + "\"" + " is working.");
    driver.navigate().back();

    }
    }

    }driver.quit();
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Are any of the links, in reality, not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of getting link text(s) and clicking, you can just retrieve the "href" attribute of each "a" tag elements**. Since the purpose is just to navigate to each url and check the links by opening and getting title, I recommend this as the better way. Below is the updated code, that worked.

**Note: I have just tweaked the existing code for solving it**

```
@Test
public void findurl() throws Throwable, IOException {
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("D:\\sites.xls");
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
    System.out.println("Program Started"+s.getName());
    System.out.println(s.getRows());

    for (int row = 0; row < s.getRows(); row++) 
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        String Urllist = s.getCell(0, row).getContents().toString();
        System.out.println("Url number "+(row+1)+": " + Urllist);       
        driver.get(Urllist);

        List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("The number of links under URL number "+(row+1)+" is: "+linkElements.size());
        String[] linkhrefs = new String[linkElements.size()];

        int j = 0;
        for (WebElement e : linkElements) {
            linkhrefs[j] = e.getAttribute("href");
            j++;
        }

        // test each link
        int k=0;
        for (String t : linkhrefs) {
            try{
                if (t != null && !t.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Navigating to link number "+(++k)+": '"+t+"'");
                    driver.navigate().to(t);
                    String title;
                    title = driver.getTitle();
                    System.out.println("title is: "+title);
                    if((title.contains("You are not authorized to view this page"))||(title.contains("404")) ||
                            (title.contains("408"))|| (title.contains("400")) || (title.contains("401"))
                            || (title.contains("403"))||(title.contains("Page not found"))||(title.contains("500"))||(title.contains("error"))||(title.contains("503 Service Unavailable")))
                    {
                        System.err.println(t + " the link is not working because title is: "+title);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("\"" + t + "\"" + " is working.");
                      //driver.navigate().back();
                    }
                }else{
                    System.err.println("Link's href is null.");
                }
            }catch(Throwable e){

                System.err.println("Error came while navigating to link: "+t);
            }

            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

        }

        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Closing the driver as the links under url: "+Urllist+" have been checked out");

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellant Answer and if u can teach how to batch the two selenium projects and that   would be run one by one automatically